# ul does not display bullets

Tags: css, html-lists, block

One of my UL is not displaying correctly.  It is both displaying things inline and also the bullets do not show.

I know that this issue is isolated strictly to my divs that are used with my tabbed interface.  I'm also assuming this is due to the hierarchy above.  (The .tabs li says to display things 'inline'.)  If I delete that, obviously the tab interface is screwed.  How can I keep my divs displaying horizontally, and have the lists inside of the div box display in a block?

Thanks!

CSS

```
    .basics ul {font-family:terminal;
         font-size:9px;
         text-transform:uppercase;
         color:gray;
         padding:0px;
         display:block;
         }


    li.basics { list-style-image: url('/bullet.png'); 
         }   

    ul b {font-family: terminal;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#fff3a2;
  font-weight:lighter;
  }


    div.tabs {
            padding:15px;
            width:760px;
            background:#000;
            color:#fff;
            border-radius: 0em 4em 1em;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            margin-left:3px;
            height:200px;
            overflow: auto;
}
    ul.tabs {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:3px;
    }


        .tabs li {
            list-style:none;
            display:inline;
        }
```

and the html code:

```
    <ul class='tabs'>
<li><a href='#tab1'>BASICS</a></li>
<li><a href='#tab2'>BIOGRAPHY</a></li>
<li><a href='#tab3'>RANDOM</a></li>
<li><a href='#tab4'>NPCs</a></li>
  </ul>


   <div id="tab1" class="tabs">

<ul class="basics">
<li><b>Full Name:</b> 
<li><b>DOB:</b> 27 May 1985; 28 YRS </li> 
<li><b>Birthplace:</b>Olinda, Brasil</li> 
<li><b>Nationality:</b>Brazilian, French, & American</li>
```

```
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do you give `tabs` class name to div as well? and what plugin you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want the top to be horizontal, and the lower one to be vertical.  I just changed your rule from `.tabs li` to  `ul.tabs li`

http://jsfiddle.net/itsmikem/3RwMn/

Let me know if that's your issue.